# Explanation of application of superposition theorem for homogenious linear ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, intuition

\begin{equation}
x^{\prime}+a(t)x+b(t)=0 \, \, \, \text{Denote by $(1)$}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
x^{\prime}+a(t)x=0 \,\,\, \text{Denote by $(2)$}
\end{equation}

> Particular solution: When the solution $x(t)$ of say $(1)$ passes throught a given point say
> $(t_0,x_0)$ i.e. $x_0=x(t_0)$ then the solution is particular.

> Example:

For example the solution of $(2)$ is $\int_{x_0}^x{du}=x_0-\int_{t_0}^{t}{a(s)x(s)ds}$ and write
$x=x(t,t_0,x_0)$
The problem here is that I dont understand why the solution of $(2)$ looks of these form, because the solution is given by
$$x^{\prime}=-a(t)x$$
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-a(t)x $$
$$ \frac{dx}{x}=-a(t)dt$$
$$ \log(x)=-\int{a(t)dt}+C$$
$$x=Ke^{-\int{a(t)dt}}$$ and when then by the condition $x_0=x(t_0)$
$$ x_0=Ke^{-\int_{t_0}^{t}{a(s)ds}}$$ but from here I don´t know how to get the form of $(2)$ in the example.

**Someone can explain me how is that the author get the form of $(2)$? it was very helpful.**

*My first goal is understand the following theorem*

> Theorem:Let us assume that $x(t,t_0,x_0)$ is solution of $(2)$ then $p(t)=\int_{t_0}^{t}x(t,s,b(s))ds$ is solution of $(1)$ and have general solution $y(t)=x(t,t_0,x_0)+\int_{t_0}^{t}x(t,s,b(s))ds$.

**I really I don´t understand how to apply the theorem to solve the equation
$y^{\prime}-\frac{2}{t}y=t+\frac{1}{t} \sin (\frac{1}{t^2})$
I know how to get the solution without this method (in fact is $y=t^2 \log(t)+\frac{t^2}{2} \cos (\frac{1}{t^2})+t^2 c$), but when I try to apply the method I fail.**

If someone can help me to understand the theorem above was vwet useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually,
$$
\int_{x_0}^x\,du = x_0 - \int_{t_0}^t a(s)x(s)\,ds
$$
is not a solution. It is an integral equation equivalent to your differential equation $(2)$.

The theorem says that $y(t) = \int_{t_0}^t x(t; s, b(s))\,ds$ is a particular solution of equation $(1)$ which satisfies $y(t_0) = 0$.

The proof is very simple:
$$
\begin{align*}
&\left[\int_{t_0}^t x(t; s, b(s))\,ds\right]' + a(t)\int_{t_0}^t x(t; s, b(s))\,ds \\&= x(t; t, b(t)) + \int_{t_0}^t x'(t; s, b(s))\,ds + \int_{t_0}^t a(t) x(t; s, b(s))\,ds \\&= b(t) - \int_{t_0}^t a(t) x(t; s, b(s))\,ds + \int_{t_0}^t a(t) x(t; s, b(s))\,ds = b(t).
\end{align*}
$$

In fact, this theorem is just a more formal approach to the method of variation of constants.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I understand the theorem, and I apply the theorem to the equation, is very simple thanks to your explanation